# Azure B2C Custom Policy note resolving PolicyId

Tags: azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy, aad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c

I have custom policy, I am trying to use output claim from TechnicalProfile, into ValidationTechnicalProfile. OutputClaim can have set of values and it looks like:

```
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="PolicyId" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" DefaultValue="{Policy:PolicyId}" />
```

In ValidationTechnicalProfile I try to compare PolicyId but it is not set and . If I trying to put a hard-codded value as Default Value, ValidationTechnicalProfile is able run the validation:

```
<ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="SetActivity_BasedOnPolicyId_Yes" ContinueOnError="true">
              <Preconditions>
                <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="**false**">
                  <Value>policyId</Value>
                  <Value>B2C_1A_SignIn</Value>
                  <Action>SkipThisValidationTechnicalProfile</Action>
                </Precondition>                      
              </Preconditions>
            </ValidationTechnicalProfile>
```

....

```
<ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="SetActivity_BasedOnPolicyId_Yes" ContinueOnError="true">
              <Preconditions>
                <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="**true**">
                  <Value>policyId</Value>
                  <Value>B2C_1A_SignIn</Value>
                  <Action>SkipThisValidationTechnicalProfile</Action>
                </Precondition>                      
              </Preconditions>
            </ValidationTechnicalProfile>
```

What am I doing wrong here? I simply want to run validation against policy that's used (we have few).
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did you set:

- The IncludeClaimResolvingInClaimsHandling metadata must be set to true.
- The input or output claims attribute AlwaysUseDefaultValue must be set to true.

Comment: yes, both of them are set to true:
`code`
..........
            <Item Key="IncludeClaimResolvingInClaimsHandling">true</Item>
........
<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="PolicyId" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" DefaultValue="{Policy:PolicyId}" />`code`

Answer (score 0):

I feel like claim resolving sometimes happens in a weird order. Try making PolicyId an input claim and do the claim resolving there, rather than in the output claims (do still leave the output claim though)